# displaying files from a directory using Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am new to JavaScript and started experimenting with Bootstrap Carousel. I wrote test code that works and displays images when I manually create the Carousel items, e.g

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/1.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
  </div><!-- .carousel -->
```

However, what I would like to do is to specify a local directory and be able to automatically load and view the images there, that is create the list of Carousel items automatically.

My questions are:

- How can I do this with scripting, e.g. using perl or python to get the list of files in the directory? How do I pass this list to Carousel in JS?
- Googling, I found that HTML5 has a File API that enables JS to access the local file system. How can I do the above using this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You must use a server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a loop in your choice of language that reads the contents of a directory and outputs the HTML.

e.g. in python

```
import os
dirname = 'img'
html = '<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">\n\t<div class="carousel-inner">'
active = "active"
for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    if ".jpg" in filename:
        html = html + '\n\t\t<div class="item %s"><img src="%s"/></div>' % (active, dirname + "/" + filename)
        active = ""
html = html + '</div><!-- .carousel-inner -->\n</div><!-- .carousel -->'
```

then obviously you need to do something with the html variable like write it to a file